# AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'load_img'

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I'm trying to run and modify a tkinter code and use 'from PIL import Image' but I got attribute error that said PIL.Image has no attribute 'load_img'. I tried to change it into Image.open() but then I got new error that said TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'target_size'. I'm not sure which part should I change to fix this error.

Here is some part of the code:

```
def predictThis(folder_path):
    from PIL import Image 
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import joblib
    from numpy import argmax

    model = joblib.load("HOG_SVM.npy")
    img_width,img_height=img_size,img_size
    label_dict = {0:'Negative COVID-19', 1:'Positive COVID-19'}

    test_Image = Image.load_img(folder_path, target_size=(img_width,img_height))
    img=np.array(test_Image)
    if(img.ndim==3):
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
        gray=img

    gray=gray/255
    resized=cv2.resize(gray,(img_size,img_size))
    reshaped=resized.reshape(1,img_size,img_size)

    prediction = model.predict(reshaped)
    result=np.argmax(prediction,axis=1)[0]
    accuracy=float(np.max(prediction,axis=1)[0])

    label=label_dict[result]   

    return "This patient is " + label + " and the accuracy of\nx-ray image recognition is " + str(accuracy)
```

This is what the error said:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\TkinterFyp\untitled3.py", line 71, in browse_button
    result = predictThis(filename)
  File "C:\Users\user\TkinterFyp\untitled3.py", line 44, in predictThis
    test_Image = Image.load_img(folder_path, target_size=(img_width,img_height))
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 62, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"module '{__name__}' has no attribute '{name}'")
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'load_img'
```

**Updated solution**: I changed the load_img into Image.open, still got another error in my code, but this attribute error is gone now, thank you!

```
def predictThis(folder_path):
        from PIL import Image 
        import numpy as np
        import cv2
        import joblib
        from numpy import argmax
    
        model = joblib.load("HOG_SVM.npy")
        img_width,img_height=img_size,img_size
        label_dict = {0:'Negative COVID-19', 1:'Positive COVID-19'}
    
        test_Image = Image.open(folder_path).resize((img_width,img_height)) #edited
        img=np.array(test_Image)
        if(img.ndim==3):
            gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        else:
            gray=img
    
        gray=gray/255
        resized=cv2.resize(gray,(img_size,img_size))
        reshaped=resized.reshape(1,img_size,img_size)
    
        prediction = model.predict(reshaped)
        result=np.argmax(prediction,axis=1)[0]
        accuracy=float(np.max(prediction,axis=1)[0])
    
        label=label_dict[result]   
    
        return "This patient is " + label + " and the accuracy of\nx-ray image recognition is " + str(accuracy)
```

Comment: You mean ```Image.open``` Method? The error is quite explanatory

Comment: Use `test_Image = Image.open(folder_path).resize((img_width,img_height))`